# ios appium automation queries

Tags: testing, automation, appium

1. Can we perform automation on preinstalled app like Facebook on ios real device using appium without having ipa/app file?
2. Can we perform automation on real ios device without having developer team id for a ios app for which we have ipa/app file?

Comment: Please provide some more context information. To help you, people need to know what exactly you are trying to accomplish and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Yes**, you can specify the app `bundleId` in the desired capabilities and attach Appium to the pre-installed application.
2. **No**. You need to build and sign the `appium-webdriveragent` app with your developer certificate to be able to install it on the real iOS device.

Comment: Do we need  paid developer account or a free account can also be used?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can automate pre installed apps in your phone. But make sure following configurations are already done:

1. "noReset" capability should be set to true. It won't install your app on every run.
2. You will need apple developer account if you want to automate it on Real Device. If you are running on simulator, developer account is not needed.